# Search or filter values in two-segment list in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, list

i have a two-segment list;

```
var list =ee.List([[101,12155],[102,12157],[103,12158]])
```

i want to search or filter for 102 and get result (12157), for 103 and get result(12158)

How can i do it ?

i find a way (below code) to get result but is there a simpliest way?

```
var list = ee.List([[101,12155], [102,12157], [103,12158]])

// get ui.select label
function findObjectByValue(slist, key) {
for (var i = 0; i < slist.size().getInfo(); i++) {
var number = ee.List(slist.get(i)).get(0)
print(number)
if (number.getInfo() == key) {
  //print('AAA')
  return ee.List(slist.get(i)).get(1);
  }
}
return null;
}

print(findObjectByValue(list, 101)) // print 12155
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to avoid `getInfo()` calls. It locks up the page, and slow down your execution. Below are a couple of different implementations. They're not very simple, but avoid `getInfo()` calls.

You have to decide how to deal with cases where the value you search for isn't present. You might want to return something, give an error, or you simply know it cannot happen and happily ignore it.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/21a7c7b22138541b424b00489128f74c

```
var list = ee.List([
  [101, 12155],
  [102, 12157],
  [103, 12158]
])

print(
  'findWithIf',
  findWithIf(list, 102), 
  findWithIf(list, 104)
)

print(
  'findByIndex',
  findByIndex(list, 102),
  findByIndex(list, 104)
)

print(
  'findMaskingArray',
  findMaskingArray(list, 102),
  findMaskingArray(list, 104)
)

print(
  'findUsingDictionary',
  findUsingDictionary(list, 102),
  findUsingDictionary(list, 104)
)


function findWithIf(list2D, value) {
  return list2D
    .map(function (tuple) {
      tuple = ee.List(tuple)
      return ee.Algorithms.If(
        tuple.getNumber(0).eq(value),
        tuple.getNumber(1),
        null
      )
    }, true)
    .cat([null]) // Not found returns null
    .getNumber(0)
}

function findByIndex(list2D, value) {
  var array = ee.Array(list)
  var keys = array.slice(1, 0, 1).project([0]).toList()
  var values = array.slice(1, 1, 2).project([0]).toList()
  var index = keys.indexOf(value)
  return values
    .cat([null]) // Not found returns null
    .getNumber(index)
}

function findMaskingArray(list2D, value) {
  var array = ee.Array(list)
  var keys = array.slice(1, 0, 1).project([0])
  var values = array.slice(1, 1, 2).project([0])
  var mask = ee.Array(ee.List.repeat(value, keys.length().get([0])))
  return values
    .mask(keys.eq(mask))
    .toList()
    .cat([null]) // Not found returns null
    .getNumber(0)
}

function findUsingDictionary(list2D, value) {
  var array = ee.Array(list)
  var keys = array.slice(1, 0, 1).project([0]).toList()
    .map(function (key) { // Turning keys into strings
      return ee.Number(key).format()
    })
  var values = array.slice(1, 1, 2).project([0]).toList()
  return ee.Number(
    ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, values)
      .get(ee.Number(value).format(), -1) // Not found returns -1
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you ver much, Daniel. I tried to search a solution with a simple command like filter... And can i ask to you, how can search in row first element?

Comment: How do you mean "search in row first element"?

Comment: i want to search for a value in first key of list, for 101, 102, 103 in my list

Comment: To see if it exists? Return true/false? Or return an index to the item?

Comment: both of them please, true/false and index of item

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9f02a10e3487009187b7cf0a43d432ce

Comment: i am gratefull to you, i tried to find a solution for 2-3 days and i can not find a solution, thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to be able to help

Comment: Daniel, can we collect of them with one function, if first key(102) exists, get second key(12157) as result of function. it will very effective solution for use...

Comment: Sorry, I don’t follow that.

Comment: Dear Daniell, can you answer this question with this link:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392824/using-expression-operators-in-if-else-conditions-without-getinfo-in-google-earth