# Using expression operators in if/else conditions without getInfo in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, for-loop, if-else

İ have a two-segment list with id and value and i want to make a new list from imageList using second element value.

i want to get the first values in first column until 100 in second colum and save the first three values in first column to another list.

```
var imageList = ee.List([
  [101, 102],
  [102, 103],
  [103, 104],
  [106, 100],
  [104, 105],
  [105, 106],
  ])
```

i define starting point with firstImageId :

```
var firstImageId = 101
```

i get list length with getInfo:

```
var size = imageList.length().getInfo()
```

And running the function:

```
var imageList = getImageList(firstImageId,imageList)
print('New image List :', imageList)
```

And there are main function and helped function finding for indexof key:

```
// functions 
function getImageList(firstImage, list) {
var cropImageList =ee.List([]);
var currentImageId= firstImageId

if(firstImageId) {
for (var i = 0; i<size;i++){
    print(i, currentImageId)
    var indexofkey = indexOf(list, currentImageId)
    var currentImageValueID= ee.List(list.get(indexofkey)).get(1)
    currentImageValueID= currentImageValueID.getInfo();
    if (currentImageValueID ==100 ) {
      print ('Break at : ',currentImageValueID)
      break;
    }
    cropImageList = cropImageList.add(currentImageValueID)
    currentImageId= currentImageValueID
    }
   }

  return cropImageList
}
// Thanks to Daniel Wiell for indexOf function
function indexOf(list2D, value) {
var array = ee.Array(list2D)
var keys = array.slice(1, 0, 1).project([0]).toList()
var values = array.slice(1, 1, 2).project([0]).toList()
return keys.indexOf(value)
}
```

The running code link is below:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/565d3ce033edcb427597a68dbea80889

[image]
The code is working but running slow because i use getInfo: I must use an expression operator to break for loop.

How can i define if/else conditions with local variables without using getInfo for below section?

```
        currentImageValueID= currentImageValueID.getInfo();
        if (currentImageValueID ==100 ) {
          print ('Break at : ',currentImageValueID)
          break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly how you want this to work. Maybe something like this:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d189fa967590801be256da2e609c5ce7

```
var list = ee.List([
  [101, 101],
  [102, 103],
  [103, 104],
  [106, 100],
  [104, 105],
  [105, 106],
])
var breakValue = 100

var secondColumn = ee.Array(list) // 2D array
  .slice(1, 1, 2) // Create subarray with the second column (12155, 12157, ...). Still a 2D array.
  .project([0]) // Convert 2D array into 1D array
  .toList() // Convert array to list

var breakIndex = secondColumn.indexOf(breakValue)
var newList = secondColumn.slice(0, breakIndex)

print(newList)
```